# How much is W40K inspired from the Incal series?

Tags: warhammer-40k, inspiration

I discovered Warhammer 40K quite late, and something struck me:

There is a french comic called the Incal, set in a Sci-Fi world led by a "perfect imperoratriz", a supposedly perfect androgynous ruler wisely leading the human empire from the golden planet. This series also features a large techno-priest sect worshipping the machines (though they're bad guys supporting the darkness)

The Incal was published from 1981 to 1988, so anterior to the first release of Warhammer 40K in 1987!

Is this enough to suppose a large inspiration from the Incal or are there other more obvious sources at this time that I would not know of?

No matter how much I searched, I could not find any mention of the Incal in the articles about W40K.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Warhammer 40k Steals influences from all over so I would not be surprised if the idea of the Emperor and the Tech Priests was not influenced by this series.

Genestealers are lifted from Alien (even to the way they reproduce in some respects)

Eldar - Elves

orks - orcs, but spelt differently so GW can trademark the name.

and so on

Comment: Tau are a homage to anime mecha.

Comment: yep basicly GW rip everything off then charge a small fortune to buy the models :)

Comment: They still make the models, and even after ripping off "everything", it is quite a feat to develop such an intricate and complete universe